# Cannot get my pc built php site to work on the web

Tags: php, required, htdocs

I have part built a php site on my pc. I do not want to have a blog style site, but do want to add a single header, single navbar and single footer to the site, and will start building a login area later.
I built it on my PC and it worked wonderfully when displaying it in IE, Chrome, Firefox and Safari, so I copied all the files into a test folder on the existing website, and this didn't work.
I got the error message

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'includes/navbar.php'     (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php5.4')
```

in /homepages/11/d95668464/htdocs/test/Projects.php on line 54
 and haven't a clue what that means.

The required 'includes/header.php and required 'includes/footer.php works correctly and in the right place  but the navbar doesn't show at all.
The navbar.php code reads:-

```
<?php

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>My Site's Title</title>
<link href="/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
</head>
<section class="navigation" data-role="navbar">
<nav>
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="news.php">News &amp; Events</a></li>
<li><a href="projects.php>Projects</a></li. 
<li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="membership.php">Join/Renew</a></li>
<li><a href="links.php">Links</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</section>
```

The code on the page reads:-

```
 <?php
 include "includes/navbar.php";
 ?>
```

Comment: Do you copy the `includes` folder as well? Always recommend to use `require_once()` instead of `include()` in order to generate **error** message instead of **warning message**.

Comment: Ref your unstyled page, you have an absolute path in your css link. This won't work if your site is now in a folder. Remove the first slash: `<link href="Styles/Site.css"....`

Comment: Thank you for the stylesheet link correction, that's sorted out the problem with the header and footer, which do display properly, and the bit where the navbar SHOULD show is now in the correct position, but not inserted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to link all of your href's to the correct place.

Right now:

```
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
```

After:(Example: Desktop is whatever folder you may have index.php in. Im just assuming.)

```
<li><a href="Desktop/index.php">Home</a></li>
```

Comment: Thank you, putting backslashes in all the links worked beautifully for making the navbar work, and also made me realise eventually that I'd typed "includes" instead of "Includes". All problems now solved

Answer (score 0):

If your file is in a folder named test within your includes folder then you have to first resolve the
path to your includes by using the following function

```
get_include_path();
```

So now you can use this function along with your previous code. below is an example:

```
    <?php

      //get the include path
      $pathToIncludes = get_include_path();

     //include the file
     include "$pathToIncludes/navbar.php";

?>
```

Here is a link to the PHP API http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-include-path.php
I hope this helps

Comment: Now sorted. I missed the capital "I". I actually put "includes/navbar.php" when I should have put "Includes/navbar.php". Thank you for making me think instead of panic.